# How to deal with patents that others hold?

Tags: law, international, design-patent

I am an aspiring inventor and in the best case scenario I will be developing smartphones but something that is a huge hurdle for me are the patents that other people hold. I mean one company patented a UI with rounded corner rectangles! Is there any way I can create mainstream devices that have patented parts without being sued?

This is the video that brought the problem to my attention -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0uv5jFaJFk

P.S. I really don't know what tags to add here so feel free to add, edit or remove tags is relevant

Comment: "I mean one company patented a UI with rounded corner rectangles" no, I'm pretty sure that didn't happen. This isn't meant to be mean or anything, but you gotta read up some of the basics if you want to develop smartphones, that doesn't all fit in one answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can create mainstream devices that have patented
>   parts without being sued?

Yes, you either avoid infringing on those patents by designing around the claims, or else you take a license from the patent holder. Those are really your only options.

Not to discourage you, but do you really expect to produce a competitive smartphone by yourself? Android or iPhones represent many thousands of man-years of effort. What I would suggest is more reasonable is to identify some aspect of a smartphone which can be improved upon and invent a solution to that. Obtain a patent and then either market the improvement (practical if it is an app) or else license the improvement to a cell phone manufacturer.

Comment: I have an idea for an AI and if it works out it will revolutionize the design industry the same way the calculator revolutionized the mathematics sector :)

Comment: @user9391457 That’s cool!  Getting patents on software and algorithms is possible, but tricky. I highly recommend working with a patent attorney or agent with specific expertise in this field. I have over 85 patents and some on algorithms and I wouldn’t dream of trying to pursue a patent without a lawyer.